# How to change the color of the text above a threshold length using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Making a Twitter tweet box like `div` which is `contenteditable` is my task.

I want to change the text color of the div after 60 characters to be red. Something similar to what Twitter does after 120 characters.

I have so far been able to work out how to change the color of the extra text, but I am stuck up at a problem with cursor position.

Here is a fiddle to my attempted code: https://jsfiddle.net/Bharadwajdaya/36sn0dqn/1/

And a snippet below:

```js
var red_string;
$('#div_editable').on("keyup", function(e) {
  //console.log
  var content = this.innerText;
  var siz = this.innerText.length;

  if (siz > 60) {
    var contentEditableElement = document.getElementById("div_editable");
    var con = this.innerText.substring(0, 60);
    red_string = this.innerText.substring(60, siz);
    var newString = "<span class='highlight'>" + red_string + "</span>";
    console.log(newString + con);
    $("#div_editable").html(con + newString);
    document.getElementById("div_editable").focus();
    setSelectionRange(document.getElementById("div_editable"), siz, siz);
    setCaretToPos(siz - 61)
  }
});


function setCaretToPos(siz) {
  console.log(siz)
  var node = document.getElementById("div_editable");
  node.lastChild.focus();
  var textNode = node.lastChild;
  var caret = siz;
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(textNode, node.lastChild.innerText.length);
  range.setEnd(textNode, node.lastChild.innerText.length);
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_editable" style="min-width: 320px; min-height: 120px" contenteditable="true">Use this place</div>
```

As you can see, applying the background color to extra text is working!

My problem is that once it reaches 60 characters the cursor or caret is moving back to start and the caret remains there and never expands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Want to change the text color of the div after 60 to be red.Similar
>   like twitter

This is tricky, of course. As long as you just want to change the color of the text after a specified length (60 in your case), whatever you have attempted is good enough. Just wrap the exceeding characters in another element have a suitable class applied to it.

There is no problem with your code as such, and you are definitely on the right track.

---

**Your Problem**:

However, the trickiness starts compounding when you want it to be dynamically adjusted. i.e. to keep typing anywhere and get the extra text highlighted on the go.

The problem, which you then face is of keeping the cursor position intact!

**Reason**:

The `contenteditable` selection ranges and offsets restart for every element node in the contenteditable itself. And those work with text nodes only. This means, if in your contenteditable div there is another element then the cursor position would be offset from within that element.

This manifests in your case when you wrap the exceeding text into a `span` to highlight those. Once you overwrite the content of your `div` after wrapping the extra text in `span`, you lose the cursor position with the context of its text node.

**Solution**:

Before, making any changes cache the current cursor position along with the text node cursor is in. Then, after making changes (*like wrapping extra text in another element and other stuff*), use `range.setStart` and `range.setEnd` on that node's `firstChild` as that will be the text node you can work the cursor with.

You can find the current node by using the `anchorNode` of the `selection` object. This return the text node on which the cursor currently is. In order to use this later on in the script, you use `parentNode` to get its parent element. This element can then be used later while setting the cursor back. In the example below, I am using the `em` tag (*like Twitter*), which is then used to get to the actual text node by picking its `firstChild`. If the cursor is in the first 60 characters zone, then you will get the `contenteditable` `div` instead of `em`.

**Here is a crude example snippet:** *<sup>(Works with Chrome, not tested with other browsers)</sup>*

Notice, how you can now start typing from anywhere and the cursor is preserved.

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div[contenteditable]'), allowedSize = 60;

reformat(div);
div.addEventListener('keyup', highlight);

function highlight(e) { reformat(e.target); }

function reformat(elem) {
  var size = elem.textContent.length, 
      wrapper, txt, firstSection, nextSection, cursorPos
  ;
  cursorPos = getCursorPosition();
  elem.dataset.size = allowedSize - size;

  if (size > allowedSize) {
    txt = elem.textContent;
    wrapper = document.createElement('em');
    firstSection = txt.slice(0, allowedSize);
    nextSection = txt.slice(allowedSize);
    wrapper.textContent = nextSection;
    elem.innerHTML = firstSection;
    elem.appendChild(wrapper);
    if (cursorPos) { setCursorPosition(cursorPos) }
  }
}

function getCursorPosition() { 
  var retVal = {};
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount > 0) { 
      retVal.node = sel.anchorNode.parentNode;
      retVal.pos = sel.getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
      return retVal;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function setCursorPosition(position) {
  var textNode, range, sel; 
  if (position.node.tagName == 'EM') {
    textNode = div.getElementsByTagName('EM')[0].firstChild;
  } else {
    if (position.pos > allowedSize) {
      textNode = div.getElementsByTagName('EM')[0].firstChild;
      position.pos = 1;
    } else { textNode = position.node.firstChild; }
  }
  range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(textNode, position.pos);
  range.setEnd(textNode, position.pos);
  sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```

```css
div[contenteditable] { 
  position: relative;
  width: 70vw; height: 120px; padding: 4px;
  margin: 8px auto; border: 1px solid #bbb;
  font-family: sans-serif; outline: none;
}
div[contenteditable]::after {
  content: attr(data-size); 
  position: absolute; top: 105%; right: 0;
}
div[contenteditable] em { background-color: #fcc; }
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" data-size="0">
  Start typing anywhere in this box 
</div>
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/rmprz6rx/**; for you to play with.

**Note**: The above example is a crude attempt. To make it cross-browser and polish off the kinks, is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change text color of input . please follow below code

```
$('input').keypress(function(){
    var len=$('input').val().length;
    if(len>60)
    {    
       $('input').css('color','red')
    }
})
```

Thanks

Comment: Please VoteUp if its helpful to you.